# UITableViewCells scroll on top after reorder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

After I reorder a UITableViewCell and scroll the tableView, the cell goes on top of the header instead of going underneath it. In my tableView, its editing property is always set to YES, and the reorder control is stretched to cover the entire cell. I've tried `sendSubviewToBack:` to send the cell to the back and `bringSubviewToFront:` to bring the header to the front, but it didn't work.

Here's the code for resizing the reorder control:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    JRBTask *task = [[[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] taskArrayWithIndex: indexPath] objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    if (![task reorderControlIsResized]) {
        //  Grip customization code goes in here...
        for(UIView* view in cell.subviews)
        {
            if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"])
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"])
            {
                UIView* resizedGripView = [[UIView alloc] init];

                // Use initial frame so it's resizing from its initial
                // position each time, not from its current position
                if (!initialFrame.size.height)
                    [resizedGripView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame))];
                else
                    [resizedGripView setFrame: initialFrame];

                if (!initialFrame.size.height)
                    [self setInitialFrame: resizedGripView.frame];

                [resizedGripView addSubview:view];
                [cell addSubview:resizedGripView];

                CGSize sizeDifference = CGSizeMake(initialFrame.size.width - view.frame.size.width, initialFrame.size.height - view.frame.size.height);
                CGSize transformRatio = CGSizeMake(initialFrame.size.width / view.frame.size.width, initialFrame.size.height / view.frame.size.height);

                //  Original transform
                CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

                //  Scale custom view so grip will fill entire cell
                transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, transformRatio.width, transformRatio.height);

                transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -139, -sizeDifference.height / 2.0);

                [resizedGripView setTransform: transform];

                for(UIImageView* cellGrip in view.subviews)
                {
                    if([cellGrip isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
                         [cellGrip setImage:nil];
                }
                reorderNeedsAdjusted = NO;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The updates are managed using the `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:` while the cell is moving, and `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` once the cell has been moved.

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{    
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] moveTaskFromIndex: sourceIndexPath toIndex: destinationIndexPath];

    // Update number of rows in section if the section is different
    if ([sourceIndexPath section] != [destinationIndexPath section]) {
        // Subtract from source section
        if ([sourceIndexPath section] == 0)
            numberOfRowsInToday--;
        else if ([sourceIndexPath section] == 1)
            numberOfRowsInTomorrow--;
        else if ([sourceIndexPath section] == 2)
            numberOfRowsInUpcoming--;
        else
            numberOfRowsInSomeday--;

        // Add to destination section
        if ([destinationIndexPath section] == 0)
            numberOfRowsInToday++;
        else if ([destinationIndexPath section] == 1)
            numberOfRowsInTomorrow++;
        else if ([destinationIndexPath section] == 2)
            numberOfRowsInUpcoming++;
        else
            numberOfRowsInSomeday++;
    }
}
```

[image: Issue]

Comment: Please add the code you use to reorder and refresh the tableview

Comment: Try this [self.tbl setBounces:NO];

Comment: How are you managing the updates, telling the table view to move the row and telling it when the edit 'session' is complete?

Comment: Maybe I'm  missing something, how do you scroll the table which is always at edit mode and reorder controls cover entire cells ?

Comment: I use a `longPressGestureRecognizer` that has the `delaysTouchesBegan` property set to yes. Once it's activated, it's disabled so the reorder control gets enabled. The longPressGestureRecognizer is reenabled quickly after its disabled using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

Comment: I added the code you asked for

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the best answer. but, It works for me.
This problem solved after IOS7.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * movedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];
    double delayInSeconds = 0.3;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [tableView sendSubviewToBack:movedCell];
    });
}
```

I hope this will help to someone :)